# Laplacian on the sphere and Moving Plane method

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Consider the sphere $\mathbb{S}^n$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, thus $\mathbb{S}^n=\{\omega\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1},\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\omega_i^2=1\}.$

I am interested in studying positive solutions to the equations of the form $-\Delta_{\mathbb{S}^n} u=f(u)$ on the sphere. Here $f$ is some non-linearity, for instance $f(u)=u^2-u$. I am interested in applying the moving plane method to these equations to deduce some type of symmetry results. Given this background, I have some questions/curiosities.

- How does one start the moving plane method on the sphere? I know on $\mathbb{R}^n$ we consider $w_{\lambda}(x)=u(x)-u(x_{\lambda})$ where $x_{\lambda}=(2\lambda-x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ if we choose to reflect about $x_1$-axis. I am not sure what is the analogous approach on the sphere?
- What kind of results can one expect to show for PDEs on the sphere using this method? In the $\mathbb{R}^n$ case, for instance, $\Delta u + u^{2^*-1}=0$ we can show that the positive solutions have the form $u=u(|x|)$ and then by solving an ODE we can deduce an explicit form of the function $u$ up to scaling and translations. For equations on the sphere, I guess it would make sense to show that the solutions are constants.

Comment: minor comment: if $f(u) = u^2$, then $f(u) \geq 0$ and the only solution to your PDE is the trivial one (doesn't detract from the main part of your question, but you may want to edit away this "distraction").

Comment: In fact, if you are looking at polynomial type nonlinearities $f(u) = u^p$, then the only non-negative solution has to be the zero solution. (Integrate the equation over $\mathbb{S}^2$, the LHS is a divergence so integrates to 0.).